# Missing CountersignedSignature type in xades4j

Tags: java, xades4j

I noticed in my document countersigned with xades4j there is no Type="..CountersignedSignature" in the Reference of countersigned signature. The same is in xades4j unit test in document.signed.bes.cs.xml.

On the other hand, in `xades4j.properties.CounterSignatureProperty` I can see the following property defined:

```
public String COUNTER_SIGNATURE_TYPE_URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#CountersignedSignature";
```

How can I force xades to use that property? If the type attribute is missing I have a problem with validating the document in other 3rd party software.

I used code written in SignerBESTest.

```
Document doc = getTestDocument();
Element elemToSign = doc.getDocumentElement();

XadesBesSigningProfile profile = new XadesBesSigningProfile(keyingProviderMy);
final XadesSigner counterSigner = profile.newSigner();
profile.withSignaturePropertiesProvider(new SignaturePropertiesProvider() {
@Override
public void provideProperties(final SignaturePropertiesCollector signedPropsCol) {
    signedPropsCol.addCounterSignature(new CounterSignatureProperty(counterSigner));
    signedPropsCol.setSignerRole(new SignerRoleProperty("CounterSignature"));
}
});
final XadesSignatureFormatExtender extender = new XadesFormatExtenderProfile().getFormatExtender();

final List<UnsignedSignatureProperty> unsignedProps = new ArrayList<UnsignedSignatureProperty>();
unsignedProps.add(new CounterSignatureProperty(counterSigner));

org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
final Element sigElem = (Element) documentSource.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature").item(0);
final XMLSignature xmlSig = new XMLSignature(sigElem, documentSource.getBaseURI());
extender.enrichSignature(xmlSig, new UnsignedProperties(unsignedProps));
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit1:**
I will add that I know the solution by modifying xades4j sources but I would be more interested with a solution which I can apply only in my source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAdES spec defines two mechanisms for managing counter signatures:

1. Use the `Type` attribute on arbitrary signatures
2. Use the `CounterSignature` property which contains a counter signature that actually is an enveloped signature (contained in the original one).

XAdES4j uses the second approach, hence not including the `Type` attribute. Also, there's no way to enforce its presence on the API. That said, I may check if it is easy to include the attribute.

Comment: If it is about changing xades4j than you can add this by modifying src/main/java/xades4j/production/DataGenCounterSig.java: `sigValueRef = sigValueRef.withType(CounterSignatureProperty.COUNTER_SIGNATURE_TYPE_URI);` (http://www.speedyshare.com/Cgc2j/DataGenCounterSig.java). I had to do it anyway but it's hardcoded. On the other hand this attribute is optional so add Type always should not break anything.

Comment: Yep, that's it. The attribute is not required because it's redundant, but it shouldn't be a problem. I'll update xades4j source.